# Eluveitie - "The Call of the Mountains". What the children's choir is singing at the end?

Tags: lyrics, language

Does anyone know the language and the text of what the children's choir is singing [at the end of the song](https://youtu.be/-w2m-TeLi6I?t=215)?

I've searched over the internet, but found nothing.

Comment: There's and official Eluveitie forum (http://forum.eluveitie.ch/index.php). You could ask this question there as well. Sometimes even Chrigel (the band's leader) interacts on the posts.

Comment: @LucasSant'Anna Thanks, Lucas. I'll ask there too.